# Which directory(s) does Babel look for plugins?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

The obvious answer would be that Babel searches for plugins in `node_modules` with a `babel-plugin` prefix, but are there any other directories that it searches in? If not, is it possible to configure Babel to look through other directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a relative or absolute path to plugins in your `.babelrc` file (or however you pass settings to babel).

```
"plugins": ["./node_modules/asdf/plugin"]
```

See this [explanation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#plugin-preset-paths).